# MongoDB inserting duplicate document within upsert

Tags: mongodb

My current situation is that I have several Writer objects which dump data into MongoDB. No unique indexes so duplicates are allowed and are a possibility, but shouldn't be.

I was checking existing data within the DB and found several documents in which the fields that should be used to match in the `upsert` phase are duplicated and contain different counters.

```
{"date": "today", "k1": "sample", "count": 5}
{"date": "today", "k1": "sample", "count": 2}
```

That is a very very simple example of what my current situation is. The `count` field should be 7 and there shouldn't be two separate documents with the same keys I use to perform the `upsert`, but this is something that barely happens and isn't much of the data... Just wondering what could be causing this?

Is there any situation where this can happen? A R/W lock?

Comment: Can you please provide an example of `upsert` query?

Answer (score 0):

for such things as counters, I would recommend using `$inc` operator https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/